# Unity light creates rare blue light on sky

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, lighting

I'm doing a Unity project where I basically have a Directional Light rotating around the map, starting on 0 to 360 degrees.

However, when it gets dark = rotation from 100 to 120 degrees I get this strange blue light coming from the sky, does anybody have any idea on how to avoid this blue thing appearing?

[Image to explain the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWCqb.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Lens Flare. Check if you have "Flare Layer" on your Main Camera and disable it.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FlareLayer.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/visual-effects-lens-flares.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows:

1. Find the little blue dot step by step and delete it. First click on the point light source in the scene, find Light->Flare, as shown below
   [image]
2. Click 50mm Zoom to find it in the project view and see its detailed properties in the Inspector. As shown below.
   [image]
   [image]
3. Click on the elements, you can find that it has 19 elements, expand each element, and find that the color of one element is blue. As shown below:
   [image]
4. That's it. Set the size to 0 and the problem is solved.
   Thank you, hope it helps you